# writing an array of bytes into a file (Large file size)

Tags: java, file, bitmap, compression

I have a grayscale images in which I get a representation of them in the form of a two dimensional array of **Bytes** with various values depending on their respective bitrate i.e (**0 ->255**). Then I apply one or more compression algorithms i.e. **(Run Length Encoding)**  to extract another array of byte with much smaller size, this represents the compression operation. from that I reconstruct the bitmap file into it's original form successfully which represents the decompression operation. 
I know that everything is going right because I get the same image back as a result of the decompression operation.

Now my problem is after doing the compression operation I want to store the resulting array into a file in which its content will be extracted back at the time of decompression. 
I've tried writing it as a **text** file

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/"+ fileName+".jrle"));
IOUtils.write(rle, output);
```

and I tried writing it as a **binary** file

```
ObjectOutputStream myStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("d:/"+fileName+".dat"));
myStream.writeObject(rle);
```

However in both cases the size of this file is way much bigger than original bitmap file size.

> 512x512 bitmap file size 32KB
>
> compressed text file size 272KB
>
> compressed binary file size 257KB
>
> bitmap's byte array size 262144
>
> compressed array size 111049

since my compressed array is actually much smaller than the original array extracted from the bitmap file how can I save as a file with a smaller size than the bitmap?

I'm not sure I've explained myself properly, please ask for more details if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to write your file in image format again and check if it reduce file size.
   // convert byte array back to BufferedImage
   InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(arrayofByte);
   BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
 
   ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File(
     "D:/name.jrle"));

Comment: Are you actually writing an array of `java.lang.Byte` or an array of `byte`? Because `java.lang.Byte` has an enormous overhead.

Comment: You should definitely not write the image data as a text file. And `ObjectOutputStream` will serialize the array into a persistent Java Object. Have you tried using `OutputStream#write` directly?

Comment: @Siguza an array of **byte**

Comment: Alright, then **E_net4** has just provided you with the solution.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a solution until I'm 100% sure it solves this problem. I'm also starting to wonder which `IOUtils` is being used in that code.

Comment: @E_net4 I just did as you proposed 
and the file size I got was 256KB sorry this doesn't solve the problem 

`   FileOutputStream fop = null;
   File file;
   file = new File("d:/newfile.txt");
   try {
    fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

    try {
     fop.write(rle);
     fop.flush();
     fop.close();
    }
`

Comment: I'm afraid that will be hard to debug without an MCVE. It makes no sense that a smaller byte array would produce a larger binary file containing nothing but that array.

Comment: @E_net4 this is the apache commons I/O API

Comment: Could you please run [this code](http://pastebin.com/GQFwm0t5) and paste the output here? Also, could it be that the 256KB are your filesystem's block size?

Comment: @Learner I figured, but in that case you weren't even writing the content as a text-encoded array. See IOUtils#write(byte[],java.io.OutputStream) : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#write(byte[],%20java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: @Siguza I modified your code a bit to fit into my code but nothing that would affect the result
here's the result of your code.

*****************
rle length: 222100
array length: 262144
*****************

Comment: @E_net4 I did, I just didn't place the code here

Comment: If the output array is `262144` bytes, then that's how big your byte array is. Also, if `rle.length` is `222100` (bytes)... then where did you get `111049`?

Comment: this rle is combined with prefix represents the number of repetitions 
222100/2 = 111050 minus one for the initial value 

even if rle is 222100, it still less than the original array extracted from the bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some math...

512 * 512 = 262144
32 KB = 32768
262144 / 32768 = 8

This means that every value in your original array actually just holds the value of a bit (which makes sense for grayscale), but takes up the space of a byte.
Now since you apply

> one or more compression algorithms

it is very unlikely that the same is true for the resulting array (`rle`), so actually before you apply the compression, you increase the size of your image by the factor 8.

Is there any particular reason you're not reading the bitmap file in raw bytes, e.g. like this?:

```
File in = new File("d:/input.bmp");
byte[] array = new byte[(int)in.length()];
new FileInputStream(in).read(array);
```

Comment: I'm using a  __BufferedImage__ object which gives me the freedom of putting  pixel values in a two dimensional array. I extract  _rle_ row by row, column by column and by zigzag traversing. 
your answer does provide an insight of what is going on but it doesn't solve the problem 
Thank you :)

Comment: Wait, actually my answer does not make sense unless your bitmap consists of only `#000` and `#FFF` pixels. The numbers do match though, and a grayscale raw 512x512 bitmap image would take up 262144 bytes = 256 KB...

Comment: for the specific example I'm presenting the bitmap is a 1-bit image which mean that it consist of #000 and #FFF pixels
but there are other grayscale bitmaps 4-bits and 8-bits

Comment: Well, then the solution depends on the way your compression algorithms work. If they operate on a one-dimensional array, simply convert that array from bits to bytes (i.e. from 8 values make one) and compress that one instead.

Comment: only one of the bitmaps is 1-bit 
as mentioned before there are 4-bits and 8-bits bitmaps too 
I know I can solve this by going JNI but I don't want to go through the trouble of doing so. 
thanks